# DB2 SQL: query for discovery if a group has only one client[CD_CLI]

Tags: db2

I would need a query to return which groups have only one client and if possible if a client [CD_CLI] in a group with only him.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A try with the limited information provided

```
SELECT CD_GR_PSZD, CD_CLI
  FROM CLI_GR_PSZD
 WHERE CD_GR_PSZD in (
    SELECT CD_GR_PSZD 
      FROM CLI_GR_PSZD
     GROUP BY CD_GR_PSZD 
    HAVING count(*) = 1)
```

The subselect checks which group have only a single entry in the CLI_GR_PSZD table and the outer SELECT is ment to select whatever columns you need.